# How to list installed packages with security patches?

Tags: server, apt, 10.04, dpkg

I would like to list all packages installed on a Ubuntu Server 10.04 that were upgraded for security reasons. Is there any tool that will list all security packages installed on a system?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: I am not certain, but I feel this may be not possible, as dpkg does not know what is the repo a package originates from, and therefore it may be impossible to determine if it was a security upgrade or not.

Answer (score 1):

if you install apt-show-versions:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-show-versions
```

and then run:

```
apt-show-versions -a  | grep "security\."
```

The output will list all packages installed from security.ubuntu.com

Comment: Is there any way to see the date it was installed?